# Передать в GET запросе ссылку на картинку и отобразить ее на странице

Tags: php, get, img

Нужно чтобы пользователь при переходе по ссылке `?image=http://example.com/1.png` на странице видел эту самую картинку, но когда я вставляю 
`<img src="'.$_GET['image'].'">` , то в коде вместо картинки

```
<img src(unknown)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в `$_GET['filimage']` - банальная опечатка, там не хватает m.. вопрос закрыт, все работает.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/178236)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov а это не дополнение — это ответ.

Comment: Arthur, в вопросе у вас `image`, а в ответе `filimage`. Вот и как об этом можно было догадаться по вопросу? )

Comment: Я приношу свои извинения :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_GET['image']?>">
```

Вы просто не открыли PHP вставку.

Comment: Так весь код уже идет в echo ' <img src="..." ';

Comment: то есть код такой: `echo: '.. <img scr="..">..';`?

Comment: @RomaDavidchuk, такие правки надо делать не правками, а ответами.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы не очень понимаете что такое `$_GET`. Это суперглобальный массив, в который записываются значения инпутов, отправляемых на сервер(когда вы заполняете форму регистрации, например, вы передаете данные через форму).

Если бы вы отправляли на сервер url картинки с помощью формы, в который :

```
<form method="get">
    <input type ="text" name = "image">
</form>
```

Тогда у вас всё должно получиться, но этого не происходит, поэтому в массиве `$_GET` и нет данной картинки.

Comment: Неверно, есть и другие параметры, к примеру - $_GET['filmname'] - он вставляется корректно.

Comment: @Arthur Тогда предоставьте, пожалуйста, код, которым вы отправляете данные на сервер, это прояснит ваш вопрос :)

Comment: Сейчас попробовал сохранять данные в сессию,

Comment: if (isset($_GET['filimage'])) {
 $filmimage = $_GET['filmimage'];
 $_SESSION['filmimage'] = $filmimage;
}

Comment: И вставлять сессию, но так же все работает кроме ссылки на картинку

Comment: @Arthur И опять таки, значит у вас не присутствует элемент с name = "filmimage"

Comment: @teran Вас чем-то смущает моё пояснение того, что такое $_GET?

Comment: @teran Если вы считаете мой ответ неправильным - тогда, вероятнее всего, вы можете дать более корректный вопрос. Если он правильный - с радостью проголосую за него :)

Comment: @Klimenkomud да в общем-то всем.  массивы `get/post` заполняются на основании типа пришедшего запроса. Для get запроса параметры передаются в URL, как у автора, `http://xxx.yy?image=....` - передан параметр `image`. То что вы приплели сюда формы это не корректно. При отправке формы методом get браузер берет все поля формы, объединяет их в соответствующую строку-запроса и затем отправляет этот запрос. То есть форма это всего лишь средство отправки запроса.

Comment: @teran может вопрос с ответом напишете про то, что же такое `$_GET`? (Не ирония, серьезно предлагаю).